# Hive SQL: Accessing Last Element of a Json array

Tags: hiveql

I have a json column called "schedule_info" with a format like the following:

{schedule: [{"date":"2020-01-01"},{"date":"2021-01-01"},{"date":"2022-01-01"},{"date":"2022-02-01"},{"date":"2022-03-01"}]}

I'm able to access the first element easily with:

get_json_object(schedule_info, '$.schedule[0].date') as first_date.

However, When I try to access the last date, I'm not able to..

I've tried "get_json_object(schedule_info, '$.schedule[-1].date')". But, this just returns the whole schedule array. I've also tried including the array length in the brackets, which didn't work as well.. Is there an easy way to do this?

I want to easily parse out data from the last element of a json array without having to explode the array.

Answer (score 1):

if you use brickhouse, `json_split` could help you like this:

```
select 
json_split(get_json_object(schedule_info, '$.schedule'))[
size(json_split(get_json_object(schedule_info, '$. schedule')))-1
] as last_date
from your_table
```

here you use `json_split` twice, one for get array element, another for get array size

or use `reverse` to eliminate one call to `json_split`

```
select 
reverse(json_split(get_json_object(schedule_info, '$.schedule')))[0] as last_date
from your_table
```

[json_split blog](https://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/hive-and-json-made-simple/)

[brickhouse github](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse)